# Get max slots from json and apply to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a upload form where once you upload and preview the image you can add it to a list depending that the list has less than the max slots filled.

**for example:**

If max slots is 5 then you can add 5 images, if more then the program will tell you to remove a image as you have hit the max slots.

my json looks as following

[image: json array]

**Error I'm Getting**

I am not getting to upload and keep getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'max_slots' of undefined
```

even though the path in my json to max slots is campaigns[index].max_slots as you can see in the image above.

Im not sure whats going wrong can someone help out please ?

**JavaScript**

```
.controller('Dashboard', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

        $scope.campaigns = [];
        $scope.preview = '';


        $scope.addImage = function (index) {

            if ($scope.length < $scope.campaigns[index].max_slots) {
                $scope.slots.push({
                    "slot_id": $scope.length + 1,
                    "base_image": $scope.preview,
                    "path_image": ""
                });

            } else {
                window.alert("you have to delete a slot to generate a new one");
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code ? Where is `$scope.addImage` called and what are the arguements ?

Comment: sure 5 mins ill update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.addImage function index variable may be has wrong value and $scope.campaigns[index] is undefined.

if your have ng-repeate loop and ng-click with addImage($index) then on click the function will pass wrong value i.e. $scope.campaigns.length.
Please use single campaign object instead of index number.

The function like

```
$scope.addImage = function (campaign) {
    if(!campaign) return;
    if ($scope.length < campaign.max_slots) {
        $scope.slots.push({
            "slot_id": $scope.length + 1,
            "base_image": $scope.preview,
            "path_image": ""
        });
    } else {
        window.alert("you have to delete a slot to generate a new one");
    }
};
```